Currently building basically an online market with ACF and php but getting errors
I am making a market in which users will have a set number of currency called leaves and coins and they can exchange these. I am using the code snippet plugin. I am very,very inexperienced with php.I have made a field group called user points which contains coins and leaves. I need to get the value of leaves and coins and display them. I also need to implement a system in which there can be transactions between leaves and coins. I am also really tired of banging my head against the wall because wordpress and php are very new to me.
I tried the following code in code snippets.
// get the current user id
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
// get a field from the user
$value = get_field('field_name', 'user_'.$user_id');

whenever i paste this in code snippets it returns the following error
Could not update snippet. The server did not send a valid response.

Please help

"I am making a market... I am using the code snippet plugin" - I would strongly suggest learning how to access your server through channels such as SSH and/or FTP, instead of relying on a plugin like this. I'm not bashing this plugin, but there is a tipping point where the site you are building outweighs edits through a plugin like this, and I think you might have crossed it. As to these specific errors, it might help to have a local copy of the site and enable debugging to see the specific errors.

The plugin does not allow you to save the code because there is an Error in your code. Remove the comma added after $user_id and your code will work fine.
Replace the
$value = get_field('field_name', 'user_'.$user_id');

with
$value = get_field('field_name', 'user_'.$user_id);

